# Combining constant and variable value for template default value

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm setting up a template in which I'd like the default value to be a combination of a constant string and a variable id value. The desired HTML output would be something like:

```
<span id="id1234" class="foo">
   Click <a href="/images/img1234.jpg">here to view image</a>.
</span>
```

In the template code for the `span`, I would like something like:

```
<span id="{{ spanid|default:'id'object.id }}" class="foo">
```

Similarly, the `a` tag would use:

```
<a href="/images/{{ image_file|default:'img'object.id'.jpg'"> here to view...
```

This doesn't work, is there a way to do this within the syntax of django templates and the `default` filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. However, `default` is merely a shortcut. In this scenario, the shortcut doesn't work, but the longer form will allow you do what you need:

```
{% if image_file %}{{ image_file }}{% else %}img{{ object.id }}.jpg{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Pratt's answer is a nice workaround, but it's not accurate that you can't achieve this with the default filter.

In my project, I just used the "add" filter to concatenate a string onto a variable value as follows:

```
{{ instance.image.url|default:STATIC_URL|add:"img/icons/my-image.svg" }}
```

UPDATE: I apologize. Upon more thorough testing, I discovered that the solution I presented here doesn't actually work. I thought that the "add" filter would apply to the default value, but it ends up being applied to whatever value the first part of the expression resolves to.

So, if there is a value at `{{ instance.image.url }}` then "img/icons/my-image.svg" gets concatenated that, which breaks it.

Comment: Thanks! I don't recall what version of Django I was using when I asked the question. Possibly the `add:` filter hadn't  been added yet.

Comment: I did the research. [This commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/49d6a82261feda6ee1bf23bb17184e932e232172) gave the `add:` filter the ability to work on something other than integers. This is from Feb 2010 and it looks like the first Django release to include that was 1.2. I think I was working on something earlier than that.